# A prove question about divisibility

Tags: divisibility

[image]

We have 4K=a+bc and 6k=b+ac, but I've tried (a+b)(a-b) or expand it directly. Neither of them works... Got trapped

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
a^2-b^2=a(a+bc)-b(b+ac)=4aK-6bk= \cdots \ddot \smile
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2442542/if-4-mid-abc-and-6-mid-bac-prove-that-2-mid-a2-b2